# Why does image size scale down when wrapped in an anchor tag?

Tags: html, css

I have some social media icons and I wanted to wrap them in an anchor tag so you could click on them, but when I did that the image scaled down to like a 10th of the size.

```html
<span class="iconspan">
                    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lil_ijoez/" target="_blank"><img src="assets/icons/instagram.png" alt="instagram icon" class="icons"></a>
                    <img src="assets/icons/apple.png" alt="apple music icon" class="icons">
                    <img src="assets/icons/youtube.png" alt="youtube logo" class="icons">
                    <img src="assets/icons/soundcloud.png" alt="soundcloud logo" class="icons">
                    <img src="assets/icons/amazon.png" alt="amazon logo" class="icons">
                    <img src="assets/icons/spotify.png" alt="spotify logo" class="icons">
                </span>
```

```css
.icons {
    width: 10%;
    padding: 2em 1em;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    transform: scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: .3s ease-in-out;
    transition: .3s ease-in-out;
}

.icons:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

.iconspan {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fpXEB.png)

Comment: Because your `img.icons` is a flex-item the `width:` property will be ignored. You should use `flex-basis` instead. That said, you don't need the `.icons` CSS class at all.

Answer (score 0):

Because `<span class="iconspan">` is a **flex container** it means that only its *immediate children* will be layed-out as **flex-items**.

That means the `.iconspan > a` will be a flex-item, but the `.iconspan > a > img` will not.

The fix is to use `display: contents;` on the `a`, this has the effect of making all of the *immediate children* of `a` the same as being immediate-children of `a`'s parent, thus the `img` will become a flex-item again.

```
.iconspan > a {
    display: contents;
}
```

---

So you can simplify your styles to this, btw:

```
span.iconspan { /* You should remove the "span" from "iconspan" btw. */
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

    span.iconspan > * {
        flex-basis: 10%;
        padding: 2em 1em;
        transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;

        /* `-webkit-transform` is unnecessary now. */
        /* Don't specify `transform: scale(1)` in the default state because that  creates a new stacking-context and harms performance. */
    }
    span.iconspan > *:hover {
        transform: scale(1.1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you’ve set their width to a percentage, which is always relative to the parent element. So instead of being 10% of the span, they are now 10% of the anchor.

Comment: I don't believe this is the case because the `width:` property is ignored for flex-items. The `flex-basis` property is used instead of `width` (though confusingly, the `min-width` and `max-width` properties are still used). Hmm, I think `flex-basis` uses `width` as its initial value if `flex-basis` is not explicitly specified.